# what does jQuery data() function do

Tags: jquery, jquery-data

I have not found what is the use of jquery function `data()`.
Can anyone give me some example of how it can be used?

Comment: Do you mean http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data or http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its really useful for associating various objects, strings, arrays, etc with a DOM element. Here is a fun hypothetical use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a").each(function(index, el){
      if(index % 2 == 0) 
         $(this).data('coolColor', 'Orange'); // Set the data
      else 
         $(this).data('coolColor', 'Purple'); // Set the data
   }).click(function(e){
      alert($(this).data('coolColor')); // Retrieve the data
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

This would select every `a` tag, and set `Orange` if its odd, or `Purple` if its even. This is not the most optimal way to write this code if this is what you really wanted to do, but it does illustrate how to use the `.data()` function.

You can also use it to store objects:

```
$("#header").data('headerSettings',{
   color: "red",
   cost:  "$25.00",
   time:  1000
});
```

Now you could access that data anywhere else on the page:

```
$("#header").data('headerSettings').color;
```

Comment: I thi8nk it assigns value to variables just like

var color = "orange"

Answer (score 3):

I think this question needs a bit more attention. jQuery's `data` API is really powerful for various use-cases.

jQuery's data function allows you to store and retrieve any associated data with any jQuery object.

Primarily, it can also be used to read `data-` attributes set on any node in the html.

**Example 1**

HTML:
`<div id="myNode" data-foo="bar"></div>`.

jQuery Code:
`$("#myNode").data("foo") //bar`

**Example 2**

Likewise I can store a value w.r.t any node too.

jQuery Code:

`$("#myNode").data("foo","baz")
$("#myNode").data("foo") //baz`

One important thing to note here is, that when one sets a data on the note using the data API, the html is not updated in the DOM. If you want to update the HTML, you might want to stick to the `attr("data-foo","baz")` method.

While one can read strings stored in HTML data attributes, you can also assign an object while storing a value using the data API.

There are various use-cases where developers link an object with a node.

e.g.

```
var obj = {
  name : "test"
}
$("#myNode").data("foo",obj);

$("#myNode").data("foo") === obj //true
```

Go ahead, [explore the API here.](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)

Answer (score 2):

It allows you to associate any type of data with a DOM element.  See [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1404-jQuery-Data-Method-Associates-Data-With-DOM-Elements-SWEET-ASS-SWEET-.htm) blog post for some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data) sums it up pretty well:

> Returns a unique ID for the element.
>
> ***Typically this function will only be
>   used internally. You will likely not
>   use the data() method in this way.*** It
>   is called automatically when necessary
>   when using the other data()
>   functionality.

Basically this function exists to support other jQuery functions.  It is best to ignore this function as it is not intended to to part of the public interface of the jQuery API.

Comment: You're referring to `jQuery.data`, while the OP is referring to `jQuery.fn.data` ... Quite different.