# purpose of data in jquery? (vs adding my own fields to Jquery objects)

Tags: javascript, jquery

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1794990/841108) question is related to mine and explains what [`.data` method](http://api.jquery.com/data/) is in Jquery.

Apart from the relation to HTML5 `data-*` element attributes (like `<p class='foo_cl' data-bar='gee'>`, for example) why would I code:

```
 $('body').data("my_lab", {some:"object"});   // §1
```

instead of

```
$('body').my_lab = {some:"object"};           // §2
```

<sup>(I am mostly interested in the case where the Jquery selector gives one object, like for `$('body')` above)</sup>

The later (§2) seems more readable and shorter, and I guess would be more efficient, than the former (§1). Of course `data` is a Jquery selector (but I could use `each` to set the `.my_lab` field, etc...)

And I might even consider changing the DOM element with the ugly looking

```
$('body')[0].my_lab = {some:"object"};     // §3 is ugly
```

<sup>(which is perhaps undefined behavior, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1915699/227299))</sup>

Of course, there is the potential issue of colliding the field name `my_lab` with some existing field in JQuery implementation; but I assume that using some common suffix (like `my_`) in field names should be enough.

FWIW, I am only interested in recent Jquery (e.g. Jquery 2.1.4) on recent Firefox (e.g. 38 or 42) on Linux.

In other words, why would adding my own fields in JQuery objects be frowned upon?

Comment: the 3rd one is fine, the first two set props on what is usually a throw-away object/collection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By doing

```
$('body').my_lab = {some:"object"};
```

You are setting value to a specified jQuery wrapper. You would not be able to reaccess the data with another selector :

```
$('body').my_lab = {some:"object"};
console.log($('body').my_lab); // will log undefined
```

This is why using data is basically more reliable

```
$('body').data('my_lab', {some:"object"});
console.log($('body').data("my_lab")); // will log {some: "object"}
```

For the 3rd option : `$("body")[0].attr = { my : "object" }` part :

The jQuery data method prevents potential memory leaks when manipulating the dom / removing elements from the page (by removing the binded data and stuff) and avoid attribute conflicts (like setting domElement existing attributes and other subtle things)

So basically, if you have jQuery in you app, you don't really have any good reason to reinvent the wheel by doing manual binding between dom element and javascript data.